# Ruby hash as class argument

Tags: ruby, class, hash

I have a class where passing in a hash as initialization argument makes the most sense. But I don't want to type the hash keys over and over every time I make a new instance of that class. Is there a shortcut for this? Each instance's hash will have the same named keys.

```
class myClass
  attr_accessor :myHash
  def initialize(myHash)
    @myHash = myHash
  end
instance1 = myClass.new({k1:v1, k2:v2, k3:v3 #...})
instance2 = myClass.new({k1:v1, k2:v2, k3:v3 #...}) 
#... If I have a bunch of instances and a bunch of named keys, this will get tedious, so I'm looking for a faster way. **The named keys will all have the same name in each instance**
```

Comment: Side note first: I'd recommend using keyword arguments instead of a Hash. Back to your question: Ruby 3.1 [introduces](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/3.1.html#values-in-hash-literals-and-keyword-arguments-can-be-omitted) an experimental(?) feature that addresses this "issue". Before that there is no other solutions (switching back to positional arguments is not a solution - its trade-offs seriously outweigh some keystrokes spared...)

Comment: `hsh = {k1:v1, k2:v2, k3:v3 #...}; instance1 = myClass.new(hsh); instance2 = myClass.new(hsh)` -- is it that you want?

Comment: Not quite mechnicov, as the values will be different with each instance.

Comment: @plshelpme if you have separate values / variables (`v1`, `v2`, `v3`, etc.), you somehow have to specify the keys that they should be associated with. How is your class / method supposed to know which value / variable belongs to which key otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the keys will always be the same, you could store them in an array, and just pass the values into the constructor:

```
    class MyClass
        KEYS = [:k1, :k2, :k3]
        attr_accessor :myHash
    
        def initialize(*myVals)
            @myHash = Hash.new
            myVals.each_with_index {|val, i| @myHash[KEYS[i]] = val}
        end
    end
    
    instance1 = MyClass.new(1, 2, 3)
    instance2 = MyClass.new("hi", "there", "foo")
    p instance1.myHash
    p instance2.myHash
```

Output:

```
    {:k1=>1, :k2=>2, :k3=>3}
    {:k1=>"hi", :k2=>"there", :k3=>"foo"}
```

Be careful to always provide the correct number of arguments though.

Comment: _"correct number of arguments"_ – also the correct order.